# How can I get a count of the numbers in a column as a total?

Tags: sql

I have this query:

```
Select ABC from ( SELECT ... )
```

It returns rows of number ABC

How can I find out the total count of all those numbers in the ABC column ? So for example if there are three rows with a count of 1,2 and 4 in the ABC column I want to get the answer 7.  Note the inner SELECT just returns one column (ABC)

Comment: If I am misunderstanding your question can you please point that out but does `sum()` not work for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `SUM`:

```
SELECT SUM(ABC) FROM (SELECT ... )
```